# Making a Tofu font

Tags: fonts

This is an odd request, but is there a font out there that is just boxes that is boxes with the code point inside. And how would I go about making one. Are there any tricks with fonts that allow a different path than just generating each box with the code point inside for each character. What I'm trying to do is make zero width joiner characters visible, but not replace the character itself. This was one of the ways I thought to do it, but I'd be open to suggestions.

[image: Tofu font example]

Specifically I want to make something close to the one in the top bar.

Comment: @Webster Try looking up _tofu font_; it's an actual thing which you'd probably need to recognise before understanding the question.. The name of the Google font Noto even comes from it, being _no tofu_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couldn't find one, so I made one. https://github.com/JuanPotato/Tofu

It's not perfect but it works. It is a script that generates a given range of characters. Working on making the characters more visible but this is ok.

Answer (score -1):

Put a stroked rectangle around each set of characters? Any of the big Adobe three will do this.

[image]

Comment: What? I think you misunderstood my question. I'm looking for a font where each of the characters look like the fallback character for non included characters (traditionally this is a box, a box with an x, or a box with the code point inside, the last one is what I'm trying to do) I want a font that is literally that. Not normal characters, and not just excluding everything so that it falls back automatically. Just boxes with letters and numbers as the entire font

Comment: This isn't what he's asking for. He wants a typeable font that displays as boxes but still has the letter information in it.

So say you write out the word dog. It appears as □□□ but when you select that and change it to say Univers it will still read dog.